# Can't set NSTextField from drawRect or mouseUp in NSView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsview

I have an NSView class and would like to set the string value for an NSTextField from either drawRect or mouseUp. The header file (.h) looks like this:

```
@interface ComposerViewController : NSView 
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *motifName; 
@end
```

In the implementation (.m) file I try to set "motifName" within drawRect like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
[super drawRect:dirtyRect];
[self.motifName setStringValue:@"Bob"]:
}
```

Or within the "mouseUp" method like this:

```
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
[self.motifName setStringValue:@"Bob"];
}
```

Neither of these works to change the displayed value of my NSTextField object.

I do have an IBAction that does display the desired text, like this:

```
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender
{
[self.motifName setStringValue:@"Bob"];
}
```

I am very confused as to why the "setStringValue" works in the IBAction method, but not the drawRect or mouseUp methods, even though they are all in the same implementation file.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Log the values of `self` and `self.motifName` in each method. I suspect `self` is not the same between `-add:` and the other methods because you accidentally have multiple instances of your class. Consequently, the outlet will be `nil` in one of the instances. Also, the fact that you named a view class as though it were a view **controller** suggests you are very confused. Finally, it's not appropriate to attempt to set a text field's value in `-drawRect:`. `-drawRect:` is for drawing and not much else.

Comment: OK, I logged `self` and `self.motifName`. `self` is always the same but `self.motifName` logs as (null) when there is a problem. Any suggestions for a fix, or an example to show how to better implement an view controller?

Comment: Ah, I think I am confused in terminology. I am not implementing a view controller. I am implementing a custom view for drawing with mouse actions, buttons, and text fields.

Comment: If `self.motifName` becomes nil, perhaps that is because it has been deallocated.  Your property has only a weak reference to it, so it looks like `motifName` has gone away and your property has been nilled out.  Where is the strong reference to the textfield, and why is it apparently no longer referencing the textfield to keep it around?  That is the angle you need to pursue; this is a memory-management bug, nothing to do with where you call `setStringValue:`, by the sound of it.

Comment: I changed the weak reference to strong for `motifName` and that has no effect. `self.motifName` continues to work in the `-add` method so that reference hasn't gone away.

Comment: The mystery lies in why `self.motifName` is not recognized within `-mouseUp`. This behavior suggests that `-mouseUp` belongs to a different object.

Comment: Aha! I have discovered that `-awakeFromNib` is being called twice! Need to track that down ...

Comment: OK, I have figured out my problem. I have two instances of NSView subclass. I got rid of one and things seems to be working. Thanks.